# How to render image within an html dynamically?

Tags: java, image

I am having some html content with images(html+images) embedded inside it on my local drive. When i open it by double clicking on browser directly, i am able to see the content with embedded images in it.

Now i have to render this content on web browser using java apis.I am able to render html content without any issue but while rendering , image is not getting rendered , instead alt text is getting rendered on browser.

I got to know that i can not set two mime types in java code to render image as well as text on same page.I want to know how can i render html content with image inside it so that it can be rendered.

Regards.

---

Code added:

```
public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException{ 
    String lsFilePath = "D:\\alf3.3\\deployment\\target\\";
    //String lsFilename = "/WEB-INF/message.properties"; 
    String lsFilename = "spcontent2.html"; 
    File loNewFile = new File(lsFilePath + lsFilename); 
    FileInputStream loFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(loNewFile); 
    FileOutputStream loFilOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(loNewFile); 
}
```

It is fine till now but i need to know how can i render an image that is referred to in file mentioned.

Comment: Post some code. How are we supposed to have any idea what you're doing?

Comment: public void readFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
  String lsFilePath = "D:\\alf3.3\\deployment\\target\\"; 
  //String lsFilename = "/WEB-INF/message.properties";
  String lsFilename = "spcontent2.html";
  File loNewFile = new File(lsFilePath + lsFilename);
  FileInputStream loFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(loNewFile);
  FileOutputStream loFilOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(loNewFile);  
 } It is fine till now but i need to know how can i render an image that is referred to in file mentioned.

Comment: The code you added doesn't do anything. And I don't understand - are you trying to generate an image? Or just serve one up? In that case, why are you involving Java at all?

Comment: Yes this code is just returning stream.I want to render/serve all images which are referred to in html file as below.This html & referred images are all stored on my local drive.<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt; text-indent: 0.5in;"><strong><span style="font-size: small; font-family: Times New Roman;"><img style="vertical-align: baseline;" src="index.jpeg" alt="test" /><br /></span></strong></p>.I need java to render it on portlet. Using java all i can render is content , no image but here, i need to render image contained in using <img> tag as it is on portal.

Comment: My idea is to convert html & image to stream & render it using this stream.

Answer (score 1):

For embedding an Image into html source page by adding content id into image source. This is usually practised while sending HTML emails with embedded images

Please refer following document for more info.

http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2111.html

Comment: Hi,Can i do like this. Create 2 servlets, s1 for html & s2 for images. Using s1, update html so that src in <img> tag will contain s2 url with iamge name. When html is rendered, s1 will render html contet & s2 used in <img> tag will be called from there & returns stream for same image  which can then be used.